# Javascript: initialize object by property

Tags: javascript, object

```
var someObject = function(arg) {
    this.property = function() {
        // do something with the argument
        return arg;
    }();
};

var obj = new someObject(some argument);
// object.property instanceof "someObject" should be true
```

When `property` of `someObject` is used, a new instance of `newObject` should be created. For example, when I use the native DOM Element's nextSibling property, a new DOM Element object instance is returned. I wonder if it is possible to create a similar structure. Or would such cause infinite recursion?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `when I use the native DOM Element's nextSibling property, a new DOM Element object instance is returned` - this is not true.

Comment: Did you forget this question?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is possible in ES5 (all latest browsers, yes that includes IE).

ES5 specifies getters and setters via the `get` and `set` keyword or the `Object.defineProperty` function so you can make functions behave like properties (think innerHTML). Here's how you can do it:

```
function Mother () {
    this.name = '';
    Object.defineproperty(this,'child',{
        get: function(){
            return new Mother();
        }
    });
}
```

So the object can now create new instances of itself simply by reading the `child` property:

```
var a = new Mother();
a.name = 'Alice';
b = a.child;
b.name = 'Susan';

alert(a.name) // Alice
alert(b.name) // Susan

a instanceof Mother; // true
b instanceof Mother; // true
```

---

Having said that, your observation about DOM elements is wrong. The DOM is simply a tree structure. You can create a similar structure yourself using old-school javascript:

```
function MyObject () {}

var a = new MyObject();
var b = new MyObject();
var c = new MyObject();
a.children = [b,c];
b.nextSibling = c;
c.prevSibling = b;

// now it works like the DOM:
b.nextSibling; // returns c
a.children[1]; // returns c
b.nextSibling.prevSibling instanceof MyObject; // true
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already provided that answer 10 minutes ago =P

Comment: Does it really matter though? I made the comment that caused you to write the answer 26 minutes ago. In 1 hour's time nobody will be able to tell which of our answers came first. So I'm going to repeat your comment on your answer which will really confuse people an hour from now :D

Comment: Well the distinction is that I haven't seen your comment since you are not getting notified about posted comments when writing an answer, while you are getting notified that new answers have been posted and it's a good practice to look at them to avoid duplicate ideas ;) Anyway +1 as well, it's still an answer of good quality!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You could set function to the property, but anyway, you will need to invoke function somehow (with `property()` notation or with `call/apply`), because function it's an object itself, and only `()` or `call/apply` say to interpreter that you want to execute code, but not only get access to function's object data.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. You can define property accessors. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the nextSibling property in the DOM is incorrect. It does not create a new DOMElement, it simply references an existing DOM Node.

When you create a sibling of an element to which you have a reference (e.g., via jQuery or document.createElement), the browser knows to update sibling and parent/child references.

So, the behavior you're trying to emulate doesn't even exist.

As others have intimated, simply accessing a property on an object is not sufficient to get the Javascript interpreter to "do" anything (other than deference the name you're looking up). You'll need property to be a function.

Comment: `simply accessing a property on an object is not sufficient to get the Javascript interpreter to "do" anything` this is not exactly true. The property can be defined as a getter so that accessing it will execute your get function which can run any bit of code you want. It only works on js engines that implements ES5 getters and setters but that's more common these days than it used to be.

Comment: slebetman is right, but do be aware of the ES5 compatibility issues, and of the fact that getters/setters aren't really properties so much as automatically executed methods.

Answer (score 0):

`nextSibling` doesn't return a *new* element, it returns an existing element which is the next sibling of the target element.

You can store an object reference as a property of another object just like you can store primitive values.

```
function SomeObject(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

var someObject = new SomeObject(new SomeObject());

someObject.obj instanceof SomeObject //true
```

However if you want to create a new instance of `SomeObject` dynamically when accessing `someObject.obj` or you want to return an existing object based on conditions that shoul be re-evaluated every time the property is accessed, you will need to use a **function or an accessor**.

```
function SomeObject(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

SomeObject.prototype.clone = function () {
    //using this.constructor is a DRY way of accessing the current object constructor
    //instead of writing new SomeObject(...)
    return new this.constructor(this.obj);
};

var someObject = new SomeObject(new SomeObject());
var someObjectClone = someObject.clone();
```

Finally with accessors (*be aware that they aren't cross-browser and cannot be shimmed*)

```
function SequentialObj(num) {
    this.num = num;
}

Object.defineProperty(SequentialObj.prototype, 'next', {
    get: function () {
        return new this.constructor(this.num + 1);
    },
    configurable: false
});

var seq = new SequentialObj(0);

console.log(seq.next); //SequentialObj {num: 1}
console.log(seq.next.next.next); //SequentialObj {num: 3}
```

Comment: Oh.. upvoting yours just to be friendly :D

Answer (score -1):

If you want `this.property()` to return a new `someObject` you can write the class as follows:

```
var someObject = function(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
};
someObject.prototype.property = function(arg) {
    // do something with the argument
    return new someObject(arg||this.arg);
}();

var obj = new someObject(/*some argument*/);
// object.property instanceof "someObject" should be true
```

If you want it to return some already instantiated version you can write the code as follows:

```
var someObject = (function() {
    var previous;
    function(arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
        this.propertyBefore = previous;//refers to the someObject created before this one
        if(previous) previous.property = this; //before.property now references this class
        //this.property will be undefined until another instance of someObject is created
        previous = this;
    };
})()

var obj = new someObject(/*some argument*/);// returns someObject already created earlier (similar to nextSibling)
```

One small note - its best practice in javascript to declare class names with a capitalized name (`SomeObject` rather than `someObject`)

Comment: your function will not work unless you invoke it, and in case you describe it - it's not property in semantic case, it's method.

Comment: @Ph0en1x Which function are you referring to?

Comment: property() - it's not a property, it's method.

Comment: Oh true he's asking for a linked list then